# Is let in "Let us...." a verb?

Tags: grammar, imperatives

Is the lexical verb *let* or *stay* in this sentence?

> "Let us stay indoors while the weather cools"

I'm wondering whether *let* is an auxiliary (or even if *let us* is an auxiliary). Or is it a "lexical" verb or "main" verb?

Comment: What do you mean, "or"? Both are verbs. And there's a third one right on their heels.

Comment: @RegDwigнt They mean is *let* a lexical verb or an auxiliary. Fair question - which Chasly has given a shot.

Answer (score 7):

It is a good question. There are two possible meanings to this sentence.

> Let us stay indoors while the weather cools.

**1.** This can be a request to someone in authority that means:

*[Please] let us stay indoors while the weather cools.*

In this case the main verb is 'let' (meaning 'allow') and 'stay' is a bare infinitive.

**2.** It can also be a first-person-plural 'imperative'.

*I suggest that we stay indoors while the weather cools.*

In this case it could be argued that the verb is 'stay' and that 'let' is an auxiliary verb that is part of the imperative structure.

---

Personally I would say that in both cases the main verb is imperative 'let' and that 'stay' is infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

At first read, the above answer sounded logical to me, but then I re-read the definitions of the types of verbs. Here's my take -

Let us stay, and 'Please' let us stay won't mean the same and will change what type of verb 'let' is.
One means a suggestion that let us stay, and the other seems to seek a permission which 'actually' needs to be given.

I'd say 'stay' or 'leave' is an action which can be taken or can be asked to be taken (stay (or leave) can be literally/actually be 'done' or is asked for, in case of permission) and hence, 'stay' is an 'action verb'. It is not something that just 'happens' but will need to be actually 'done'.

Next, if 'let' is seeking permission then 'to let' or 'to prevent/prohibit' is an actual 'action' needs to take or 'do' and it is not something that will just 'happen'. So, in this case, it will be an 'action verb'.

In case 'let' is a suggestion, like 'let's' stay - in this case 'stay' is something that will actually happen (again it will be action verb), and 'let' will be something that is helping us make 'sense' out of the sentence, and hence, in this case, it will be a helping/auxiliary verb.

More Examples: 
He grows tired after working hard. - here 'grows' is something that happens as a result of his 'working hard', he cannot actually 'do' it in this context, and it links this verb to the 'state' he is in (tired) after working hard, and hence, this will be a linking verb.
The same word: 
He grows lemons - here 'grows' is something he actually does, it is not something that will just 'happen'. So 'grows' here is an action verb.

Take this example - I was asked to stay indoors while the weather cools.
Now, stay is an action ( which I need to take - I can actually 'do' it)
asked - this again is an action which was actually taken.
was - this helps the action word/verb 'asked' to make more sense and help join the sentence. So here, 'was' is the helping/auxiliary verb.

I'm not a teacher, but that's my view after reading the definitions of action verbs, helping verbs, and linking verbs.

Hope this helps give a perspective.